# glGen* vs glCreate* naming convention

Tags: opengl

I've browsed the OpenGL standards looking for an explanation for this... why do some objects (shader objects) use functions starting with the prefix **glCreate** and some objects (buffer objects) use function starting with the prefix **glGen**?  Is there a semantic reason for this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `glGen…` functions go back to OpenGL-1.1 (`glGenTextures`) and are used to create object names without actually initializing the object. However most of the time those functions are used to create only one object name at a time. So instead of passing them a pointer to a buffer and the size of the buffer you could most of the time just return a single integer.

When 3Dlabs introduced GLSL they tried to break with the old `glGen…` convention to modernize the OpenGL API.

Yes, this is a bit inconsequential and frankly I'd prefer the GLSL API to use the `glGen…` naming convention. But we're stuck with `glCreateShader` and `glCreateProgram` and that's it.

If you want to have a single naming convention you may write the following wrappers:

```
GLuint glCreateTexture(void) { GLuint name; glGenTextures(1, &name); return name; }
GLuint glCreateBuffer(void) { GLuint name; glGenTextures(1, &name); return name; }
...
```

Comment: interesting, another reason to not buy 3dlabs cards (jk)...  now that you mention it the fact that these functions RETURN values is also a bit of the old cognitive dissonance.

Comment: hmm, i see WebGL tends in the same direction, choosing gl.createBuffer() instead of the more traditional gl.genBuffers()

Comment: This answer could definitely use updating for OpenGL 4.5 and direct_state_access, since we've now got both glGenTextures and glCreateTextures, among others.

Comment: @Jagoly: Kind of. Unfortunately glCreateTextures introduces yet another API semantics; it's closer to glGenTextures than glCreate{Program,Shader}, due to returning an array of textures into a buffer supplied by the user (unlike glCreate{Program,Shader} which delivers the actual object name as function return value). C'mon guys, make up your mind…

Comment: isn't this a little stupid to make such a mess in the naming convention and make developer confused...

Comment: @RobertWang: Yes it is. OTOH there is a OpenGL extension called "direct state access" (DSA) that became core in OpenGL-4.5 which required extra APIs for creating texture handles and for this introduced `glCreate…` counterparts to the `glGen…` functions. In a pure DSA program you'll find no calls to `glGen…` functions. So it became consistent retroactively by that.

Comment: I see. thanks. does that mean DSA is a recommend/better way to call APIs than traditional glGen... functions?

Comment: @RobertWang: API naming conventions are not really a suggestion. But the DSA methods kind of line up "old stuff" with the API of the newer stuff. The main advantage of DSA is, that with a 100% DSA codebase (hardly to be found at this date, because DSA is a rather new development) you no longer have to care about global state… which simplifies a lot of things. If you throw bindless textures into the mix you're getting pretty close to what you have with Vulkan, D3D12 or Metal.

Answer (score 14):

Since OpenGL 4.5, my understanding is that the glCreate* functions are generally meant to be used with direct state access functions, introduced in OpenGL 4.5, whereas the glGen* require binding the respective buffer, array, texture etc. before they can be used since they are uninitialized until then.

e.g. from https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/html/

> **glGenVertexArrays** (...) The names returned in arrays are marked as used, for the purposes of glGenVertexArrays only, but they acquire state and type only when they are first bound.
>
> **glCreateVertexArrays** returns n previously unused vertex array object names in arrays, each representing a new vertex array object *initialized to the default state.*

One may argue that the glCreateProgram makes sense too. If it produces an initialized object it is in accordance with the rest of the syntax.