# GL_INVALID_ENUM with glMapBuffer()

Tags: opengl

I'm completely new to OpenGL, so I assume I'm probably doing something stupid here. Basically I'm just trying to memory map a buffer object I've created, but `glMapBuffer()` is returning `NULL` and giving an error code of `GL_INVALID_ENUM`. Here's the relevant code that's failing:

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_vao);
glBindVertexArray(m_vao);

glGenBuffers(1, &m_vertex_buffer);
glNamedBufferStorage(m_vertex_buffer,
                     BUFFER_SIZE,
                     NULL,
                     GL_MAP_READ_BIT | GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertex_buffer);
void* vertex_buffer = glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_READ_ONLY);
if (!vertex_buffer)
{
  GLenum error = glGetError();
  fprintf(stderr, "Buffer map failed! %d (%s)\n", error, gluErrorString(error));
  return;
}
glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

This is printing:

```
Buffer map failed! 1280 (invalid enumerant)
```

According to [the docs](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glMapBuffer.xhtml), that error gets returned if the target is not one of the available target enums. That said, `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` is definitely  listed as available.

Am I just doing something wrong here?

Comment: "*Am I just doing something wrong here?*" You mean, besides not using DSA functions to map the buffer? You're already using `glNamedBufferStorage`; why not map it with DSA too?

Comment: @NicolBolas, I tried using glNamedBufferStorage as well but had the same issue (except the error code was GL_INVALID_OPERATION). I reverted back to the older version on the theory that it might be better supported by my drivers. No luck though.

Comment: ^ I meant glMapNamedBuffer, sorry. Too late to edit the comment. (BTW I just saw your profile - I've actually been reading your OpenGL tutorial. Thanks for putting that together).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it helps anyone else, I had multiple issues:

- `glGetError()` returns the first value from a queue of errors. The `GL_INVALID_ENUM` I thought I was getting was actually from a previous (unrelated) call.
- Per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441430/glgen-vs-glcreate-naming-convention), `glGenBuffers()` allocates a new buffer name, but the buffer is not actually **created** until it gets bound to a context using `glBindBuffer()`. I was instead calling `glNamedBufferStorage()` immediately, which resulted in a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` since the buffer didn't actually exist yet. So basically I should always use `glCreate*()` instead of `glGen*()` when using DSA.
- I *believe* that `glNamedBufferStorage()` is for **immutable** buffers, and `glNamedBufferData()` is for buffers that you can modify, although I'm not entirely clear on that from the documentation. In any case, I'm using `glNamedBufferData()` now.

I'm now able to successfully map and write to my buffers after the following setup:

```
glCreateBuffers(1, &m_vertex_buffer);
glNamedBufferData(m_vertex_buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
void* vertex_buffer_ptr = glMapNamedBuffer(m_vertex_buffer, GL_WRITE_ONLY);
```